# Providing factory method to Lazy<T> when factory exists on another lazy instance?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

### The Problem

I found myself needing an instance of an `IObjectContext` interface that should never be null, but wanting to delay instantiation until after some required resources have been loaded.

I decided to approach this with [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx), but quickly ran into an issue -- I also require an [`IObjectSet<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642094.aspx) that is never null and lazy instantiated. The problem is this:

```
// lazyObjectSet needs to be created directly after lazyContext, but I need to 
// delay instantiating both. The desired factory method exists on lazyContext,
// but accessing lazyContext.Value instantiates context before it is needed:
//
var lazyObjectSet = new Lazy<IObjectSet<TEntity>>(lazyContext.Value.FactoryMethodName);
```

---

### My Solution

I would like suggestions for improvements on my approach, or alternative approaches to the problem.

```
public static class LazyExtensions {
    private class LazyFactory<T, TResult> where TResult : class {
        private readonly Lazy<T> _dependency;
        private readonly MethodInfo _factory;

        public LazyFactory(Lazy<T> lazyDependency, MethodInfo lazyFactory) {
            // Argument null checks omitted for brevity
            Contract.Requires(typeof(TResult).Equals(lazyFactory.ReturnType));
            Contract.Requires(lazyFactory.GetParameters().Count() == 0);

            _factory = lazyFactory;
            _dependency = lazyDependency;
        }

        public TResult Invoke() {
            return (TResult) _factory.Invoke(_dependency.Value, null);
        }
    }

    public static Func<TOut> GetLazyFactory<TIn, TOut>(
        Lazy<TIn> dependency, MethodInfo factoryInfo) where TOut : class {
        return new LazyFactory<TIn, TOut>(dependency, factoryInfo).Invoke;
    }
}
```

Now I can use `GetLazyFactory()` to write the following, and the context should not be instantiated until `lazyObjectSet.Value` is accessed:

```
var lazyFactory = LazyExtensions.GetLazyFactory<IObjectContext, IObjectSet<TEntity>>(
    new Lazy<IObjectContext>(factory.Create), 
    typeof (IObjectContext).GetMethod("ObjectSet"));

var lazyObjectSet = new Lazy<IObjectSet<TEntity>>(lazyFactory);
```

How can this be improved, and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: A better question might be: is using reflection the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conjunction with the rest of the code, the following line exhibits a bug:

```
Contract.Requires(typeof(TResult).Equals(lazyFactory.ReturnType));
```

The problem is that my `IObjectContext.ObjectSet()` method has the generic return type `IObjectSet<TEntity>`, and `lazyFactory` doesn't have type information for `TEntity`.

Specifically, the type parameter for `lazyFactory` is unknown because it's obtained using [`GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx). As a result, [`Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.equals.aspx) returns false and the constraint fails with an exception.

I solved the problem by modifying `GetLazyFactory` to accept a method name string and obtain the `MethodInfo` itself, calling [`MakeGenericMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) as necessary.

```
public static Func<TOut> GetLazyFactory<TIn, TOut>(Lazy<TIn> dependency, string factoryName)
    where TOut : class
{
    Type outT = typeof(TOut);       // Expected return type of factory method
    MethodInfo factoryMethodInfo =  // Should return TOut
        typeof(TIn).GetMethod(factoryName); 

    if(outT.IsGenericType)
    {
        // Get generic type argument of TOut, making sure exactly 1 exists.
        Type tParam = outT.GetSingleGenericArgument(); 

        // We must specify the generic type or Type.Equals() will yield false.
        factoryMethodInfo = factoryMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(tParam);
    }
    return new LazyFactory<TIn, TOut>(dependency, factoryMethodInfo).Invoke;
}
```